# Can you perform a Query on a Table that exists but has no Mode in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, find

Rails auto-generated a join table in this relationship :

```
# User.rb
has_and_belongs_to :topics

# Topic.rb
has_and_belongs_to :users
```

I want to query the join table, `topics_users` directly for a to obtain an ID's.

This strategy I feel would be the fastest at getting the User ID's from the Topics, rather than looking up the Join Table, looking up the Users, and Getting the ID's from the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to you can execute manual sql queries as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT id FROM users_topics WHERE etc")
```

Comment: How do you display or work with the results? It just returns a MySQL object.

Comment: It returns a Mysql::Result which is an array of arrays - [[1], [2]] in this case. Just iterate over it in the normal fashion.

Comment: if I perform the method `all_hashes` on it, I can get it to display a series of hashes, but I can not iterate over them.